# Can Oracle Coherence run embedded in application server process like Hazelcast?

Tags: oracle-coherence

We're considering using Coherence to replace Hazelcast. Now we run Hazelcast in embedded mode, inside our application server process. I wonder if Coherence can also run like this? I couldn't find document confirming this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 popular ways to deploy Coherence with an application server:

1) Client/server - using the Coherence*Extend protocol, or using the HTTP / REST protocol. This allows an application server to be operated independently of the Coherence cluster, and is simpler and safer as a result, but can have slightly higher latency as a result.

2) In cluster, but using separate dedicated cache servers - this is called "storage disabled" in which the application server doesn't use any memory for managing the Coherence data, and instead separate processes are running in the cluster just to manage that data.

3) In process (i.e. embedded into the application or into the server) - this is the original Coherence deployment model, but has grown less popular due to the other models.

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to use a mix of this architecture?

I mean: I have some servers (about 4 sub-system deployed in JBoss cluster) that need to write + read from the cache, and a lot of other servers (about 60) that need only to read only from the cache.

Can I mix "In cluster" + Coherence*Extend?

Comment: Do you also Know if it is possible to mix full replication on a group of machine and near cache on others?

Comment: Yes, you can, but it's a bit complicated. The best way to do this is to use the partitioned cache service to store the data, and then where you want it to be replicated, use a continuous query cache on an "all filter" (i.e. all the data). That gives you instantaneous local access to the continuous query cache. Other machines that don't want to burn as much memory can just use a size-limited near cache instead.

Comment: hi @cpurdy, any documentation on how to do the "in process" way? Searched but could not find any.

Comment: Just include Coherence.jar in the application (or if necessary for some advanced technical reason, in the application server classpath itself). The Coherence API is then available within the application. Just use it :-)

Answer (score 1):

I have been using Oracle Coherence for 5+ years. 
To answer your question, YES - Coherence can run within an application process. It is called as in-process. There is out-of-process & in-process deployment approaches, which it supports.

I wrote a blog few years back (please refer) on session management using Coherence - hope it helps:
http://ankurkumar78.blogspot.in/2011/08/oracle-coherence-best-practices-in.html